# AWS Glue IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid type name uuid'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to ETL a table with a UUID in one column into a postgres table but I'm struggling to load the UUID column into the destination postgres table as a UUID type.

Using the following line of code:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = foo, mappings = [("id", "string", "id", "uuid")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

I receive the following error when I run the glue job:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid type name guid'
```

Does anyone know how I can store the id as a UUID in the destination database table?

Also, I can't seem to find the list of supported data types that I am allowed to use in the `ApplyMapping` call. Does anyone know where to find these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Glue does not support uuid as datatype. Following document gives the details about all the supported datatypes in AWS glue ETL, which are extension to pyspark types :

[AWS Glue datatypes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-types.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-types-awsglue-datatype)

Comment: To clarify ... I fixed this by just storing the uuids as strings in the target database

Comment: @t_warsop we are also facing same issue; could you help us with solution you implemented. Did you retain `id` as `UUID` type in target table? if yes, then what solution you implemented; could you help us with sample code...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So neither the AWS DynamicFrame, nor the underlying Spark DataFrame support handling a UUID type object. However, the JDBC driver for Postgres does support a [configuration property](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) called "stringtype". When it is set to "unspecified", it will cause the JDBC driver to attempt to cast strings to the correct column type lower in the stack, below the level of the Spark DataFrame.

You can configure the behavior in an AWS Glue pyspark script like this.

```
datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = transform2, catalog_connection = "<<glue catalog connection>>", connection_options = {
    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://<HOST>?stringtype=unspecified"
    "customJdbcDriverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver",
    "customJdbcDriverS3Path": "s3://<YOUR_S3_BUCKET>/postgresql-42.2.23.jar",
    "database": "<DATABASE_NAME>", 
    "dbtable": "<TABLE_NAME>"
}, transformation_ctx = "datasink")
```

Obviously this is an unintended usage of this driver configuration parameter, so it's a hack for sure, but it does appear to work and is probably the best solution available at the time of this writing.

It is also worth noting that AWS DynamicFrame and Spark DataFrame support a BinaryType. So it's possible to write your UUIDs into the DataFrame as a binary buffer and then store them using a Postgres bytea(16) column. This is much more efficient than converting all your uuid columns to char(36) and doesn't require any JDBC level hacks. It does, of course, require migrating all existing data and adjusting the application logic to read this new column correctly. So overall it's a much bigger change than the one suggested above but probably "more correct" overall if you can do it.